# Disable Gradle "Executing" Messages

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am building a simple Kotlin application that gets user input then prints it to the screen:

```
while (true) {
    val PROMPT = ">>> "

    print(PROMPT)
    val userInput = readLn()

    println(userInput)
}
```

But whenever I run this application using `./gradlew run`, I get these messages:

```
<========---> 80% EXECUTING [2m 30s]
>>> ===---> 80% EXECUTING [2m 31s]
<==========---> 80% EXECUTING [2m 34s]
```

Here's what I tried to remove them:

In my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {
    standardInput = System.`in`
    standardOutput = System.out
    logging.captureStandardOutput(LogLevel.QUIET)
    logging.captureStandardError(LogLevel.QUIET)
}
```

I have also tried changing the `LogLevel` to `LogLevel.ERROR` for both `captureStandardOutput` and `captureStandardError`, yet I still get these "Executing" messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run Gradle in cmd with the following tags:

- [`-q` or `--quiet`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#setting_log_level) - logs errors only
- [`console=plane`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_customizing_log_format) - disables all color and other rich output in the console output

For example:

```
./gradlew -q --console=plain run
```

But when I tested these flags, I ran into a problem: Gradle doesn't print text message to console without newline character before user prompt, i.e. the `print("smt")` method has no effect, but the `println("smt")` method works fine. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Using `--console=plain` may also be needed.

Comment: @Slaw depends on goals. I think that `-q` will be enough to resolve that problem

Comment: If I recall correctly, `-q` doesn't stop the "progress bar" (e.g., `===---> 80% EXECUTING [2m 31s]`). Using `--console=plain` does. Though if you don't combine it with `-q`, then a bunch of other stuff that would normally be printed on one line will instead be printed line-by-line.

Comment: @Slaw let me check. It will take a few minutes

Comment: @Slaw you are right! The combination of `-q` and `--console=plane` makes sense